# How to save the count() group by from mysql into a php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need to save the count(activity_type) group by user_posted_to into a variable from mysql query

```
$query = "
        SELECT user_posted_to, COUNT(*)
       FROM activity_log_table 
       WHERE 
           post_type = 'discussion' 
          AND activity_type = 'Like' ";
$query .= "AND activity_timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND activity_type <= CURRENT_DATE ";
$query .= "GROUP BY user_posted_to ORDER BY activity_timestamp DESC LIMIT 25";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);



 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $user_posted_to = (int)$row['user_posted_to'];
            $timestamp = time();
            // I need to insert the count into this table for number_assert
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO top_weekly (user_id, number_assert, timestamp) VALUES ($user_posted_to, $timestamp)";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
            $confirm_query2 = confirm_query($result2);

        if($confirm_query2) {
            echo "success query 2";
        } else {
            echo "failed query 2";
        }
    }
```

i expect to save the count() group by into a php variable and to be able to use it later on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to alias the « COUNT(*) » to something else, like « cnt ». Then you can access the column by name after fetching, as demonstrated below :

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        user_posted_to, 
        COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM activity_log_table 
    WHERE 
        post_type = 'discussion' 
        AND activity_type = 'Like'
       AND activity_timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
        AND activity_type <= CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY user_posted_to 
    ORDER BY activity_timestamp DESC 
    LIMIT 25";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "user_posted_to: " . $row["user_posted_to"]. " - Count: " . $row["cnt"] . "<br>";
    } 
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: i'm a procedural programmer but thanks for your answer it is right as Henry suggested

Answer (score 1):

Add and AS label to the COUNT(*) then you will be able to readout that label in the row you get.

```
$query = "SELECT user_posted_to, COUNT(*) AS varCount FROM activity_log_table WHERE post_type = 'discussion' AND activity_type = 'Like' ";

$nummerOfCount = $row['varCount']
```

Comment: so I can take varCount and use it as a $varCount variable ?

Comment: I added it into the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot henry ! this solved my problem big time !